# Image will not display in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I created a Gui using NetBean's built in GUI builder and now I am trying to add code that allows the user to chose an image, that should be displayed in an ImageIcon within A JLabel, but I can not get the image to display.

```
  private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
     CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mainPanel.getLayout());         
     cl.show(mainPanel, "uploadImage" );

     File im1 = null;
     JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
     FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "JPG, GIF, PNG Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(mainPanel);

    try {
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {       
                im1 =  chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        else {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        BufferedImage buff = ImageIO.read(im1);

        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(imagePanel.getWidth(), imagePanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, imagePanel.getWidth(), imagePanel.getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();          

        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon (resizedImage));
        picLabel.setVisible(true);

        imagePanel.add(picLabel);// this is the Jpanel that should displpay the image 
        this.validate(); // this refers to the frame that holds all of the components
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I've tried validate and revalidate on the frame and the panel holding the image icon but nothing seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the repaint() method after adding the image.